# C# incorrectly formatting DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, formatting

I've got a web application written using Visual Studio 2012 targeting .Net 4.5 and historically it's been deployed manually by building the solution, zipping and then ftp'd onto the production server.

I'm looking to automate this deployment, so I've got a build server which hosts Jenkins CI, and I use this to build the source using MSBuild.exe and then run the NUnit tests.

When I run my build script locally it works just fine and all the tests pass.  However when I run the script on the build server (doesn't have Visual Studio installed, but has the SDK) the build is successful, however some unit tests fail.

I've looked into the failures and it turns out that there's a few strange issues occurring for example date formatting doesn't work.

```
myRequest.Date = new DateTime(1970, 2, 1)
...
myRequest.Date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy"));
```

On my local machine, this works correctly and formats the date as **01-02-1970**.  However on the build machine, the test fails because the date is formatted as **02-01-1970**

Comment: Have you checked that the Windows Region settings are the same on both machines?

Comment: I am not sure, but I had the same problem and I had to specify Culture as UK in web.config. and the second option was to set the culture zone on the server

Comment: I'll try changing the region!

Comment: changing the location didn't work, I went to Region -> Location and changed this to United Kingdom, is that the right place?

Comment: What type of variable is myRequest? Please post more code...

Answer (score 0):

You've explicitly specified the order day-month-year, so I don't believe you are getting the result you say you're getting.  For example. all of the following cultures will give the same result, "01-02-1970":

```
string usDate = date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-US"));
string deDate = date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", new CultureInfo("de-DE"));
string gbDate = date.ToString("dd-MM-yyyy", new CultureInfo("en-GB"));
```

Changing the regional settings or `CurrentCulture` smacks of "cargo-cult programming" to me.  Instead, I suggest you debug on the build machine that's causing the problem and trace exactly what's happening - are you sure you're not looking at the wrong place in the code?

Comment: My task was to automate the build, testing and deployment process without touching the code.  The result to therefore update the region settings on the build server

Comment: @lisburnite, my point is that I don't believe the line of code you've identified is returning the result you say, and that I don't believe that changing the regional settings will have any effect.  So debug to find out what is really happening.

Answer (score 0):

I had to change the region settings on the build server to be the same as my local machine.